# Report Customization

Tags: reporting, analytics, reports-api

I've been working on a report for awhile now, and I've built it with the information to display that I need.  The problem I'm having is that when I run the report The 3 fields that are grouped only step down and to the right about a half inch.  I need them to look like a pivot report.  What is the best way to go about increasing the spacing on a ran report. Thanks in advance.

Report before it's ran.
[image]

[image]
Report after being ran.  It looks horrible. There is only 4 nbsp's in the html code.

Comment: You need put a field in the vertical grouping section, otherwise it will default to the summary layout not the matrix.

Comment: @Girbot I actually have a summary report with the same info.  I really want it to look like the bottom picture, just spaced out like the top one.  I tried your suggestion, and it just congested the report. I'm trying to remove redundant names. Thanks.

Comment: Getting SFDC reports to conform to some desired layout other than the ones supported by the Reports engine can be an exercise in futility. You might want to consider using something like Conga Composer wherein report output can go straight to Excel and you have more control over the formatting

Comment: @crop1645 Thanks for your input.  I've come to realize nothing is easy in salesforce development.  But that's what you have to deal with when you're in a multi-tenant platform.  I was just hoping someone on stackexchange has conquered a similar problem.

Comment: actually, I might reword your last comment  to 'nothing is easy in Salesforce if they didn't design it to be customizable; things that are designed to be customizable can be very easy to do'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nwillard,

Unfortunately, Salesforce reporting will not let you create a report like an excel tabular pivot table. You can only have two "labels" or non-value fields in the left hand section of the matrix. The only pivot-like capabilities in Salesforce reporting come when you are pivoting value fields (numbers, currencies, etc.).

If you really need a pivot view, I would suggest looking into analytics software like Tableau or Qlikview that can be hooked up to your Salesforce instance. You may also want try the excel Connector: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=office_excel.htm&language=en_US